# You do not have access to the AdSense account

Tags: firebase, admob, adsense

I have a Firebase account and I am trying to add Admob to it. Whenever I click on Get Started button I get this error

> You do not have access to the AdSense account that is connected to your AdMob account

I opened another account which has Admob and Adsense but it seems I cannot connect to it. Should they be the same email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. Each AdMob account must be associated with both an AdSense account and a Google Ads account. AdMob uses each of these accounts to manage certain parts of your AdMob account.
You can find detail information on [how Admob use Adsense en Google Ads here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356173?hl=en).